# Adding attributes for polygons to vector layer with polygon intercept using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I have a vector layer with polygons. There's only 1 attribute – NAME – corresponding to the name of the polygon.

I need to create a new vector layer containing the line segments representing the borders between the polygons. I want each border to be identified by the names of the 2 polygons that meet at that border.

I can get the line segments, and name of one of the polygons, but not the other. Here's my code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
vl = QgsVectorLayer("MultiLineString", "Borders", "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("NAME1", QVariant.String), QgsField("NAME2", QVariant.String)])
vl.updateFields()

import itertools
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

for geom1,geom2 in itertools.combinations(layer.getFeatures(),r=2): 
 if geom1.geometry().intersects(geom2.geometry()):
  geom = geom1.geometry().intersection(geom2.geometry())
  fet = QgsFeature()
  fet.setGeometry(geom)
  fet.setAttributes(geom1.attributes())
  pr.addFeatures([fet])
vl.updateExtents()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

How can I obtain attributes of `geom2` and add to the `NAME2` field in the new vector layer? I know I need to use something like:

```
for geom1,geom2 in itertools.combinations(layer.getFeatures(),r=2):
 if geom1.geometry().intersects(geom2.geometry()):
  geom = geom1.geometry().intersection(geom2.geometry())
  fet = QgsFeature()
  fet.setGeometry(geom)
  id1 = provider.fieldNameIndex("NAME")
  id2 = provider.fieldNameIndex("NAME")
  attribute = [None] * len(pr.fields())
  attribute[id1] = geom1.attributes()
  attribute[id2] = geom2.attributes()
  fet.setAttributes(attribute)
  pr.addFeatures([fet])
```

But this gives me NULL values. How should I change this code?

Comment: Your issue is because 'setAttributes' method from **QgsFeature** needs as argument a list of attributes (please, see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code works as you expect. Issue was because 'setAttributes' method from **QgsFeature** needs as argument a list of attributes.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
import itertools

layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
crs = layer.crs()

vl = QgsVectorLayer("MultiLineString", "Borders", "memory")
vl.setCrs(crs)
pr = vl.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("NAME1", QVariant.String), QgsField("NAME2", QVariant.String)])
vl.updateFields()


for geom1,geom2 in itertools.combinations(layer.getFeatures(),r=2): 
    if geom1.geometry().intersects(geom2.geometry()):
        geom = geom1.geometry().intersection(geom2.geometry())
        fet = QgsFeature()
        fet.setGeometry(geom)
        fet.setAttributes([str(geom1.attribute('NAME')), str(geom2.attribute('NAME'))])
        pr.addFeatures([fet])

vl.updateExtents()

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

I tried it out with shapefile of following image; where it can be observed attributes table for both layers (original and resulting layer).

[image]